# FreeNAS: ZFS array 'removes' multiple drives

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, zfs

Got a bit of an alarming situation here. Hope someone can help me figure out what's going on.

**Background**

I've built a ZFS server running FreeNAS for backup and storage about five years ago, starting with a 6x 8TB disk RAID-Z2 array. This continues to operate fine to this day. The device has no additional roles beyond providing cifs shares.

The server spends most of its time offline (as it's a huge power hog), occasionally powering up to do backups, copy files, scrub volumes and whatnot.

A few years ago I decided to expand this setup (as planned) with another six disks, also in RAID Z2. This array, connected to the same hardware as the first, has 'removed' a few individual disks now (one at a time), which I replaced. These disks all pass surface scans, so I assumed there was an incompatibility of some sort with ZFS.

**Removed drives**

Last week I powered it up again, and out of the blue it decided to remove two drives. As this is the maximum that can be lost without losing the volume, I immediately ordered two new ones, did a full read test with Western Digital Data Lifeguard (which both passed) and replaced the old ones. The array resilvered and was labeled 'HEALTHY' again. The removed drives I additionally also tested with DLG, and surprisingly they passed as well. After resilvering completed, I then proceeded to run backups to this volume.

**THE PROBLEM**

I just found out FOUR out of six drives have now been removed, making the volume UNAVAILABLE rather than DEGRADED. This includes the two brand new drives, and two other ones, one of which about five days ago also temporarily caused trouble but seemed to have recovered on its own. The fourth removed one seems to have operated without issue until just now.

My question is: **what could have caused this?** (and of course, how can I hopefully restore the volume and finally, prevent this from happening again?)

I have a few avenues that I'm investigating, would appreciate any input on these :)

**Power:**
As this happened under duress, I'm wondering if this might be a power issue? The PSU is a Seasonic G-Series G-550W PCGH-Edition, which should be sufficient (HDDs are additionally in staggered power up iirc). What also speaks against this, is that both arrays usually scrub at the same time, and resilvering two drives on the now UNAVAILABLE volume completed without problems. And I copied some large files to the first array a few days ago, which did not cause problems either. If one 6x8TB array can stay healthy under duress, why would the other array not be able to under the same circumstances? Note that they have not been put under stress simultaneously, and there have been longer periods of time before where there was no problem with both volumes.

**Temperature:**
The two most troublesome drives are located in a second drive bay that sits behind the main one. Although the air that reaches these will have increased temperature, I've also added a fan behind the second bay that actively sucks out the air from there (which is funneled specifically around this bay by means of sealed dividers), so there should be a higher air flow.

I'm afraid I haven't gotten around to setting up HDD temperature monitoring yet (unless there's a default feature I'm not aware of). CPU temperature is monitored, but of course no help in this regard. The troublesome disks have also disappeared from the reporting overview, so I can't even see their i/o history right now.

**Controller:**
The second array is connected to a Delock PCI Express SATA controller. I'm wondering if this this thing is perhaps unable to cope with the data throughput? In this case I'm not sure how I would be able to test this though. And I'm also not sure why four drives get removed, and two others in the same array have continued to operate normally to this very moment (reported as 'ONLINE').

**SATA cables:**
These I still have to test, so tbc. The cables are neatly tucked away and do not make strong bends, but they can of course fail over time. The chance of four drives being unavailable in the same array on the same day due to cabling, puts this very low on my list of suspects though.

**Hardware:**

- **Main board**: MSI C236M WORKSTATION (with six SATA ports, in use by array #1)
- **CPU**: Intel Xeon E3-1275 v5
- **Memory**: Kingston KVR21E15D8K2 x2 (ECC)
- **PSU**: Seasonic G-Series G-550W PCGH-Edition
- **Second controller**: Delock PCI Express x2 Card -> 10 x Internal SATA III - LP
- **Array #1** (6x 8TB in RAID-Z2, operating stable for 5 years now):

  - WD80EFZX x3
  - ST8000VN0002 x2
  - ST8000DM002 x1
- **Array #2** (6x 8TB in RAID-Z2):

  - WD80EFAX (no issues)
  - ST8000VN0022 (once removed before, DLG passed and currently operating normally)
  - WD80EFAX x2 (existing drives, now also removeded)
  - WD80EFZZ x2 (new replacement drives, now removed)
  - ST8000VN0022 x2 (removed a few days ago, replaced with the WD80EFZZ x2)

Comment: You say "reject" but that's not something ZFS does. Please provide the relevant exact error message from `zpool status`.

Comment: Apologies, 'removed'. This is quite stressful, so I'm a bit less accurate than usual.

Comment: _(General FYI: FreeNAS/TrueNAS issues are best dealt with on the [TrueNAS forum](https://www.truenas.com/community))_ The issue is likely your SATA cables and/or how close they are to 12V/5V power cables and you'd be receiving CAM Status errors if so. If using thin SATA cables _(e.g. Silverstone's CP11, similar style by CableCreation)_ they have less shielding and are more prone to signal corruption from 12V/5V cables near them _(I've used both types of the thin cables in my Silverstone DS380 for 7yrs and it's a PIA to arrange the cables just so in order for signal corruption to not occur)_

Comment: There's an interesting avenue of thought! Regular flat cables (similar to [these](https://www.amazon.com/Rosewill-10-Inch-Serial-Locking-RCA-RU-10-SA3-RD/dp/B00552PDG4)), however likely in close proximity to the power cables. I'm not currently near my server, but I will investigate. Figured it was more of a hardware than a Free/TrueNAS issue btw, hence here :)

Comment: @MiG Cable you linked shouldn't have EMF signal corruption since it contains the normal amount of shielding, however when it comes to eSATA cables for your Delock controller, cable quality & length matters - for reliable signals, 3ft shouldn't be exceeded and even then it's a toss up on the cable quality. I normally always recommend cables from MonoPrice due to their high quality, low cost, and lifetime warranty, however the only eSATA cables I've never had an issue with are those that came with my Silverstone TS431U's _(same EMF signal mitigation applies, keep them away from power cables)_

Comment: _(Cont'd...) Anything surrounding TrueNAS (and legacy FreeNAS - it was discontinued years ago) is best dealt with on the TrueNAS forum since iXsystems developers (the company who built and maintains TrueNAS and FreeNAS before it) check the forum daily, as do experienced users, whereas it's a toss up on SuperUser/StackExchange since many aren't familiar with it_

Comment: @JW0914 thanks, I might post there as well (will select or post the answer here as well if I manage to solve it). As I've already gone through the writeup here however and I won't be able to do any work on her until after the weekend, I might as well see which suggestions bubble up first!

Comment: They're not eSATA ports/cables on the DeLock controller by the way, regular SATA ones. Power and SATA cables on array #1 have more distance between them iirc, the second array has its disks in different physical places however so there might be touching of power cables. And [this comment](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/SATA-cables-Is-there-a-difference-97/#comment-3018783698) makes me wonder if the current cables are sufficiently shielded for this speed.

Comment: @MiG to determine the issue, you'll want to view your kernel/system log from boot up until when the issue occurs _(my hunch is you'll see a bunch of `CAM Status` errors)_, as well as the output that occurs when the pools are attempted to be mounted _(`CAM Status` errors will also populate over the CLI selection UI once it's fully booted)_. If you're unable to determine the issue, please post the kernel/system logs _(I can't recall if everything is populated within the kernel log)_ within a code box _(if it exceeds the 30K character limit, please post on PasteBin and provide a link)_

Comment: update: I've ordered higher rated SATA cables, will test this theory when I'm back home. Happy to hear other avenues I could pursue in the mean time. I'll pull the syslog when I can.

Comment: Update: replaced all the cables and physically distanced them from the power cables. Again, one drive gets removed by ZFS. I've changed ports on the controller for that drive as well, to no avail. This will not relate specifically to that drive (that for as far as I know, is healthy), but now I'm wondering if the SATA controller gets enough airflow past it. That *could* explain why the catastrophe happened during the first backup towards that volume, and how four drives got kicked out at the same time (vol recovered). Will put some direct cooling on it at the next round and continue testing.